# Code/Approach Golf: Find row in text file with too many columns

Tags: text-parsing

Given a text file that is supposed to contain 10 tab-delimited columns (i.e. 9 tabs), I'd like to find all rows that have more than 10 columns (more than 9 tabs).  Each row ends with CR-LF.

Assume nothing about the data, field widths, etc, other than the above.

Comments regarding approach, and/or working code would be extremely appreciated.  Bonus for printing line numbers of offending lines as well.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**, as pointed out by the commenter (thanks!), you can assume the data doesn't contain tabs or CRLF's.

Comment: If the "data" contains tabs or CRLF's, you're not going to be able to reliably do this given the information above. Otherwise, it's just a CSV; any parser will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF>10{print}' <filename>
```

Or, with line numbers:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NF>10{print NR; print}' <filename>
```

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner.  I think I need to specify

    `awk -F"\t" 'NF>10{print NR ":"; print}'`

but other than that, seems to work.  Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  Without specifying the field separator, this would work only if no field contained a space.  Will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a regular expression:

`(.*\t){10,}`